# How to post request in java to get the response in JSON

Tags: java, post, oauth, httpclient

I want to post the request in same formate.

```
    POST /mga/sps/oauth/oauth20/token HTTP/1.1
    Host: example.com
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Authorization: Basic aaabbbCCCdddeeefffGGG
    client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy&grant_type=authorization_code
    &code=3v6MJzt9vKtRkxpTFnkJG3IyspWC2k
    &redirect_uri=xyz%2Ffolder
```

I have Implemented but getting bad request and unable to print the post content what I am sending I also want to get the json response after sending this request.

```
String urlParameters  = "grant_type=authorization_code"+"&redirect_uri="+session.getAttribute("redirect_uri")+"&code_verifier="+session.getAttribute("codeVerifier")+"&code="+session.getAttribute("code")+"&state="+session.getAttribute("state");
        byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
        URL url = new URL( "https://example/oauth20/token" );
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
     
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
       Integer.toString(postDataLength ));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host","example.com");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","clientID=xyz");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        DataOutputStream wr = new 
       DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(postData);
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
        conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: What have you tried and what problem are you having? There exist a number of HTTP clients for Java

Comment: Please refer to this:
[Java HttpRequest JSON & Response Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816335/java-httprequest-json-response-handling)

Comment: I updated my question with the sample that till now I implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options.

1. You can start with **Java HTTP Client** - [Refer](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-http-client)

> The HTTP Client was added in Java 11. It can be used to request HTTP
> resources over the network. It supports HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2, both
> synchronous and asynchronous programming models, handles request and
> response bodies as reactive-streams, and follows the familiar builder
> pattern.

2. **Apache HttpClient** - [Refer](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-post-http-request)
3. **RestTemplate** - [Refer](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)
4. **JAX-RS Client** - [Example](https://www.baeldung.com/jersey-jax-rs-client)
5. **Spring 5 WebClient** - [Example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient)
6. **OkHttpClient** - [Example](https://www.baeldung.com/okhttp-post)

> [Comparison](https://reflectoring.io/comparison-of-java-http-clients/)

Comment: I implemented one but Getting error bad request and also unable to print the the posted request.. will you check once